# Efficiently searching a doubly-linked list for a value with a pointer constraint?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity

I have been given this problem to solve:

> Suppose you're given a doubly-linked list and a pointer to some element of that list. Let's suppose that you want to search the list for some value v, which you know exists somewhere. Using no pointers except p, design an Θ(m)-time algorithm for finding v, where m is the distance between p and the node containing v. Do not modify the input list.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this? The only way I can think of doing this destructively modifies the list.

Comment: @Dukeling Could you be more specific? How would it be pretty simple?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [templatetypedef has the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23036212/1711796), but the below solution came to mind, based on the original phrasing of the question, which states that the list can't be "destroyed or shuffled", which might imply that modifying it is okay if you can change it back again - even if this is not true, I still think this is an interesting approach.

---

It can easily be solved with 2 pointers, right? One to go forward and one to go back, moving both at the same time until you the value you're looking for.

Now this is all well and good, except that we're only allowed to have 1 pointer.

If you think about a double linked-list, we know that the previous node's `next` pointer is just a pointer to the current element, so, if we were to lose it, we could just set it up again.

So we could use `p.prev.next` as free storage (and `p.prev.prev.next`, given a similar argument).

So, we could only use one pointer going forward, and store the one going back in `p.prev.next`, moving it appropriately as we go along.

Some Java-esque pseudo-code ignoring end-of-list checks and not finding it for simplicity (I think it's already complicated enough):

```java
if p.data == v
  return v

p = p.next
p.prev.next = p.prev.prev

while not found
  if p == v || p.prev.next == v
    p.prev.next = p                   // restore p.prev.next
    return v
  p = p.next
  p.prev.next = p.prev.prev.next.prev // set up p.prev.next from p.prev.prev.next
  p.prev.prev.next = p.prev           // restore p.prev.prev.next
```

Comment: Thanks @Dukeling! thats a creative solution!

Comment: Mind-blowing. **That was beautiful**. Even though I would choose @templatetypedef answer as accepted, this is very, very clever and absolutely genius.

Answer (score 5):

As a hint: What happens if you take one step forward, two steps back, four steps forward, eight steps back, etc.? How many total steps will it take to find the element?

When doing the analysis, you might find it useful to sum up a geometric series. If it helps, 1 + r + r<sup>2</sup> + r<sup>3</sup> + ... + r<sup>n-1</sup> = (r<sup>n</sup> - 1) / (r - 1).

Hope this helps!

Comment: How can I step forwards and backwards at the same time, with only one pointer?

Comment: @Genadi My apologies, my initial answer didn't work. I've updated the answer to give a different hint.

Comment: Thank you, I thought about this, but I think it will take m^2 in worst case (Arithmetic progression) because you have to go one forward, two back, three forward, four back etc. not exactly as you described.

Comment: @Genadi If you use an arithmetic progression (one step forwards, two back, three forward, four back, etc.), you're right that it takes time m^2. However, try using a geometric progression: 2^0 forward, 2^1 back, 2^2 forward, 2^3 back, 2^4 forward, etc. and see what happens.

Comment: I think this way misses some nodes unvisited.

Comment: @Genadi Oh, to clarify - as you go backwards and forwards, you look at the values of all the nodes you encounter.

Comment: That's not O(m). Moving x steps forward or backward always requires you to pass through x nodes, and you will be bouncing on the right and left of the original place of p repeatedly. Doesn't sound like O(m) to me.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves This does work out to O(m). Think of it this way - the maximum number of steps you take in any direction is at most 4m (since you keep doubling the distance each time and stop as soon as you find the number you want). The total number of steps taken is then 4m + 2m + m + m / 2 + m / 4 + m / 8 + ..., which is bounded from above by m(4 + 2 + 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...). That second term converges to 8.

Comment: +1, no idea why this doesn't have any upvotes, it's clearly correct. Maybe you can include the idea behind this, i.e. that always doubling the number of entries that you check makes sure that only very few entries are checked often and most entries are checked at most a constant few times? I'm sure you will agree getting the idea is more useful than getting a solution.

Comment: I would upvote it, but I still don't quite get where 4m comes from. Anyway, late night here, I guess I'll just try to look at this again tomorrow.

Comment: You sum over all 2^i from i=0 to i = log(4m); that is a [finite geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometric_series#Geometric_series) and has a value linear in m.

Comment: Sorry @templatetypedef, but as much as I understand it, if I have to look at the values of all nodes I encounter, this is just same as the idea I said before, which takes m^2.

Comment: @Genadi No, it isn't; arithmetic series and geometric series behave differently, and increasing the range you search by 1 and doubling it each time thus also behave differently.

Comment: @Genadi The algorithm is correct, this should be the accepted answer. In fact, the algorithm is O(3m): if the target value is in a node to the right of p, the number of "jumps" it performs is given exactly by log(3m-1)-1; if it is to the left, it performs log(1+3m)-1. In either case, summing over all 2^i yields something that is O(3m). Like G.Bach mentioned, the properties of geometric series, and the fact that the distance is doubled, make it behave differently from the OP's original idea.